# Full-Screen IconList in Jetpack Compose Main Navigation

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

How can I ensure that the IconList in my Jetpack Compose Main navigation view occupies the entire screen when used within a Scaffold component, considering that I've attempted to utilize modifiers like LazyVerticalGrid.modifier.fillMaxHeight() and fillMaxSize(), without achieving the desired outcome?

EDIT:

Made some changes into my code based on @EthanWu suggestions, density doesnt consider padding applied with topbars

```
@SuppressLint("UnusedMaterial3ScaffoldPaddingParameter")
@Preview
@Composable
fun HomeScreenPrev() {
    TotalApplicationTheme {
        val functionalities = listOf(
            Functionality("Search", "Search functionality", Icons.Default.ShoppingCart),
            Functionality("Settings", "Settings functionality", Icons.Filled.Face),
            Functionality("Like", "Like functionality", Icons.Default.ThumbUp),
            Functionality("Warning", "Warning functionality", Icons.Default.Warning),
            Functionality("Search", "Search functionality", Icons.Default.Search),
            Functionality("Settings", "Settings functionality", Icons.Default.Settings),
        )
        HomeScreen(functionalities = functionalities)
    }
}

@SuppressLint("UnusedMaterial3ScaffoldPaddingParameter")
@Composable
fun HomeScreen(functionalities: List<Functionality>) {
    Scaffold(
        topBar = { MainTopBar() },
    ) { ActionPanel(functionalities = functionalities, modifier = Modifier.padding(it)) }
}

@Composable
fun ActionPanel(functionalities: List<Functionality>, modifier: Modifier) {
    val density = LocalDensity.current
    with(density) {
        val eachHeight =
            (LocalConfiguration.current.screenHeightDp) * density.density / (functionalities.size / 2)
        LazyVerticalGrid(
            modifier = modifier, columns = GridCells.Fixed(2)
        ) {
            items(functionalities) {
                TaskCard(it, modifier = Modifier.height(eachHeight.toDp()))
            }
        }
    }
}

@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun TaskCard(functionality: Functionality, modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    Card(modifier = modifier,
        shape = RectangleShape,
        border = BorderStroke(1.dp, Color.LightGray),
        colors = CardDefaults.cardColors(
            containerColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.tertiary, //Card background color
            contentColor = Color.Black  //Card content color,e.g.text
        ),
        onClick = {
            /*TODO*/
        }) {

        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(8.dp)
                .fillMaxWidth()
        ) {
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(8.dp))
            Icon(
                imageVector = functionality.icon,
                contentDescription = null,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .size(48.dp)
                    .align(Alignment.CenterHorizontally)
            )
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(8.dp))
            Text(text = functionality.name, style = MaterialTheme.typography.titleSmall)
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(4.dp))
            Text(text = functionality.description, style = MaterialTheme.typography.bodyMedium)
        }
    }
}
```

Current outcome

[image: Current Screen with cards]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use "Layout Inspector" to find out what the layout looks like.

This [guide](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/layout-inspector) from Android Developers would be helpful.

However, you might find that you should set the height of each row of your grid to reach what you want to do.

To do that, you could try to get the current layout height and divide it by the number of your columns, then set the each item's height to the value.

```kotlin
val density = LocalDensity.current
with(density){
    val h = LocalConfiguration.current.screenHeightDp*density.density/(listItem.size/numberOfColumns)
    LazyVerticalGrid(
    ...
    ){
        items(...){
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                          .fillMaxWidth()
                          .height(h.toDp())
            ){
                ...
             }
        }
    }
}
```

and the result would be like:

[image]

edit:

here is an example:

```kotlin
val density = LocalDensity.current
Test2Theme {
    // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
    Scaffold(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        val listItem = listOf("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6")
        val numberOfColumns = 2
        with(density) {
            val eachHeight =
                LocalConfiguration.current.screenHeightDp*density.density/(listItem.size/numberOfColumns)
            LazyVerticalGrid(
                columns = GridCells.Fixed(numberOfColumns),
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(it)
                    .fillMaxSize()
            ) {
                items(listItem) {
                    Box(
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .fillMaxWidth()
                            .height(eachHeight.toDp())
                            .border(
                                BorderStroke(1.dp, Color.Black)
                            )
                    ) {
                        Text(
                            text = it,
                            textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

the result of different resolution

[image]

[image]

edit:

The way above is only for fullscreen.
If you would like to get a component size, Modifier.onGloballyPositioned passes the size after composition.

so to achieved your goal, it would be like:

```kotlin
val listItem = listOf("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6")
val numberOfColumns = 2
var eachHeight by remember {
    mutableStateOf(0.dp)
}
LazyVerticalGrid(
    columns = GridCells.Fixed(numberOfColumns),
    modifier = Modifier
        .padding(it)
        .fillMaxSize()
        .onGloballyPositioned {
            eachHeight =
                with(density) { (it.size.height / (listItem.size / numberOfColumns)).toDp() }
        }
) {
    items(listItem) {
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .height(eachHeight)
                .border(
                    BorderStroke(1.dp, Color.Black)
                )
        ) {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

and the result would be like:

[image]

or you can create a custom layout like

```kotlin
@Composable
fun MyGridLayout(
modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
row: Int,
col: Int,
content: @Composable ()-> Unit,
){
Layout(
    content = content,
    modifier = modifier
) { measurables, constraints ->
    //calculate each children's width & height
    var placeable = measurables.map {
        val width = constraints.maxWidth/col
        val height = constraints.maxHeight/row
        var c = Constraints(minWidth = width, maxWidth = width, maxHeight = height, minHeight = height)
        it.measure(c)
    }
    //then place them
    layout(constraints.maxWidth, constraints.maxHeight) {
        var yPosition = 0
        var xPosition = 0
        var mCol = 1
        placeable.forEach {
            it.placeRelative(xPosition, yPosition)
            if (mCol % col != 0) {
                xPosition += it.width
            }
            else {
                xPosition = 0
                yPosition += it.height
            }
            mCol+=1
        }
    }
}
```

and use it like

```kotlin
Scaffold(
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
    topBar = {
        TopAppBar(
            ...
        )
    }
) {
    val listItem = listOf("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6")
    val numberOfColumns = 2
    MyGridLayout(
        modifier = Modifier.padding(it).fillMaxSize(),
        row = listItem.size/numberOfColumns,
        col = numberOfColumns
    ){
        listItem.forEach { str->
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .border(
                        BorderStroke(1.dp, Color.Black)
                    )
            ) {
              ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Both results are the same.

Comment: I don't entirely understand the logic behind using the number of columns to calculate the height of each cell, I tried to implement what you show here but [there is still empty space](https://imgur.com/a/mP8XRL8)

Comment: Sorry for that mistake, I have updated the answer, "numberOfColumn" should be the number of columns in each row, in this case, it should be 2.

Comment: It somewhat works, current problem now is that density its not taking the [space of the TopBar into consideration](https://imgur.com/a/7uckxsk)

Comment: ```LocalConfiguration.current.screenHeightDp```  retrieves the height of the device's screen. If you are going to get a component size, this should not work correctly.

Comment: The custom GridLayout worked perfectly